# Vigenere Cipher for sentence with whitespaces

Tags: python, cryptography, vigenere

I want to make a vigenere cipher program for sentences.
For example the message is "Introducing my best friend carly" and the keyword is "climb"

```
y = "Introducing my best friend carly"
target_length = len(y)

def repeat_string(a_string, target_length):
    number_of_repeats = target_length // len(a_string) + 1
    a_string_repeated = a_string * number_of_repeats
    a_string_repeated_to_target = a_string_repeated[:target_length]
    return a_string_repeated_to_target

a_string = "climb"

print (y)
print(repeat_string(a_string, target_length))
```

The output is

```
Introducing my friend carly
climbclimbclimbclimbclimbcl
```

While the output that i wanted is

```
Introducing my friend carly
climbclimbc li mbclim bclim
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One way is using itertools and looping over the original message:

```
import itertools
y = "Introducing my best friend carly"
target_length = len(y)
a_string = "climb"


def repeat_string(a_string,y):
    repeated_word = itertools.cycle(a_string)
    return "".join([next(repeated_word) if letter.isalpha() else letter for letter in y])



print (y)
print(repeat_string(a_string,y))
```

output:

```
Introducing my best friend carly
climbclimbc li mbcl imbcli mbcli
```

edit: this should keep any punctuation,
input:

```
y = "Introducing, my best friend carly.
```

output:

```
Introducing, my best friend carly.
climbclimbc, li mbcl imbcli mbcli.
```

Comment: thankyou so much! what if i want to add one more condition, if there is a punctuation, to keep the punctuation? i added elif letter in string.punctuation , but error.

Comment: @c.jungc, I added the answer. It keeps the punctuation. There is no need for an elif statement. Or am I misunderstanding you and you do want to decode the punctuation?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I run it wrong. Your answer already keeps the punctuation